# Beamer - enumerate

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I would like to make enumerate not overlay-aware.

```
\begin{enumerate}

\begin{frame}

 \item one 

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\item two
\pause
\item three
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\item four

\end{frame}

\end{enumerate}
```

The problem is the pause that increase the numbering.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? First frame should have `1. one`; second frame should have `?`...

Comment: Don't use `frame` inside `enumerate`. Use the opposite.

Comment: The opposite is a lot of work. I have a big list.

Comment: Replace `\pause` with `\item<+->` but I have no idea what this will do when you are mis-nesting environments like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\framebreak` and `overlay` awareness is lost.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item one
    \framebreak
    \item two
    \item three
    \framebreak
    \item four
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But I am still not sure of having understood the requirement.

Comment: Overlays are not supported in allowframebreaks